# gridname.getGridParam('selrow') is null

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the code below. Please let me know how i can get the selected row data in jqGrid.

I tried using the below code:

```
function getlist()
{   
    var grid = $("#gridname");
    var rowKey = grid.getGridParam('selrow');
    if (rowKey)
        alert("Selected row primary key is: " + rowKey);
    else
        alert("No rows are selected");
}
```

Here i am getting "rowkey" as null.

This is the function i have used to load json data to jqgrid:

```
function loadvalues() {    
        $("#gridname").jqGrid({
            datastr: myDataS,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
            autoencode:true,
            caption: "&nbsp;",
            pgbuttons : false,
            viewrecords : false,
            pgtext : "",
            pginput : false,
            rownumbers:true,
            cmTemplate: {sortable:false},
            loadonce: true,
            cellsubmit : "clientArray",

            colNames: ['col1','col2'],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'col1',
                index: 'col1',
                width: 0
            },{
                name: 'col2',
                index: 'col2',
                width: 0
            }
          }]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `var rowKey = grid.getGridParam('selrow');` (where `var grid = $("#gridname");`) can set the variable `rowKey` to `null` in two cases:

1. You execute the code *before* jqGrid is created from the empty table `<table id="gridname"></table>`. You will have almost the same results if there are no element with `id="gridname"` at all.
2. It's no row selected in the grid at the moment of executing of the code.

You posted *separate* code of `getlist` and `loadvalues` functions. Thus it's difficult to say what problem you have.

By the way, the function `loadvalues` can be executed **only once**. It *creates*  the grid from the empty `<table id="gridname"></table>`. During creating it will be modified to in relatively complex structure of dives and tables. So one can't call the function `loadvalues` more as once. During the next call jqGrid just tests, that the grid is already created and do nothing. If you want **recreate** the grid in the function `loadvalues` then you should add `$("#gridname").jqGrid("GridUnload");` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to call the getlist() function on the click of hyperlink(using formatter) of col1. The grid wouldn't have loaded by then, like you have stated in the first point.
I just corrected it and its working. :) 
your posts has helped me a lot. Thanks again :)

Comment: @NamrathaSreedhar: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. Welcome on the stackoverflow!